# For loop repeats halfway through

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image, sorting

I have an array of images that are sorted in descending order. I want to set that array to a list of images on my website. During the for loop to set the images, it gets exactly halfway through the for loop and then reverses the loop starting from the middle and working its way back to the start.

```
function sortBy(sort){
  if (sort == "newold"){
    var sortedImages = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("img"));
    sortedImages.splice(-1,1);
    sortedImages.sort(function(a,b){
      var contentA =parseInt(a.dataset.added,10);
      var contentB =parseInt(b.dataset.added,10);
      return (contentB - contentA);
    });
    console.log(sortedImages);
    var unsortedImages = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("img"));
    unsortedImages.splice(-1,1);
    console.log(unsortedImages);
    for(i in sortedImages){
      console.log(sortedImages[i].dataset.added);
      unsortedImages[i].src = sortedImages[i].src;
      unsortedImages[i].alt = sortedImages[i].alt;
      unsortedImages[i].dataset.download = sortedImages[i].dataset.download;
      unsortedImages[i].dataset.added = sortedImages[i].dataset.added;
      unsortedImages[i].dataset.supports = sortedImages[i].dataset.supports;
      unsortedImages[i].dataset.maker = sortedImages[i].dataset.maker;

    }
  }
}
```

It should list the dataset.added value in descending order, each element has a set integer starting at 1 and going up from there. 
[list of the dataset.added values as it runs through the for loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BOk7.png) The arrays at the top of that screenshot are both in the right order, first one is sortedImages and second is unsortedImages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
unsortedImages[i].dataset.added = sortedImages[i].dataset.added;
```

DOM nodes in both arrays are the same and `unsortedImages[i]` refers to some node in `sortedImages`. You change `added` attribute on a node in `unsortedImages` and it gets changed in `sortedImages`.

To avoid this you can  replace your `for in` loop with the following code:

```
const attrs = sortedImages.map(node => ({
  src: node.src,
  alt: node.alt,
  download: node.dataset.download,
  added: node.dataset.added,
  supports: node.dataset.supports,
  maker: node.dataset.maker,
}))

attrs.forEach((item, i) => {
  unsortedImages[i].src = item.src;
  unsortedImages[i].alt = item.alt;
  unsortedImages[i].dataset.download = item.download;
  unsortedImages[i].dataset.added = item.added;
  unsortedImages[i].dataset.supports = item.supports;
  unsortedImages[i].dataset.maker = item.maker;
})
```

Comment: So how can I make the img tags on the page update without doing that? If I don't have those then they don't update at all.

Comment: So you want to sort images on the page without moving DOM element just by changing their `src` and `alt` attributes, right?

Comment: Well if there is a way to move the DOM elements I can do that, I just want to reorder the images the easiest way I can.

Comment: @jimmyshadow1 I have updated the answer, please have a look.